# After Framework upgrade , Workflow 3.5 serialization exception on unloading instance

Tags: asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation

We are running state machine workflow 3.5 on Asp.Net web application.

After upgrading the .Net framework from 3.5 to 4.6.1 we are getting serialization exception when calling instance.Unload()

I tried adding Thread.Sleep(1000) before Instance.Unload() and it worked

My question is how can I fix this problem without using Thread.Sleep(1000).

Note that we are initializing a new WorkflowRuntime in every time we use workflow

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue is we didn't specify the manual scheduler and kept the runtime use the default automatic scheduler which is using a different thread to handle the workflow.

Check the manual scheduler section in [this article](https://odetocode.com/articles/465.aspx)